# How to use -Pandroid.debug.obsoleteApi=true on the command line

Tags: android, gradle, flutter

I'm getting  the following error:

`* Error running Gradle:
ProcessException: Process "project/path" exited abnormally:`
when I try to build my flutter project.

It says it is caused by these 3 obsolete API errors:

`WARNING: API 'variant.getJavaCompile()' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'variant.getJavaCompileProvider()'.`

`WARNING: API 'variant.getMergeAssets()' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'variant.getMergeAssetsProvider()'.`

`WARNING: API 'variantOutput.getProcessResources()' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'variantOutput.getProcessResourcesProvider()'.`

It tells me to run  `-Pandroid.debug.obsoleteApi=true on the command line` to see what's calling those methods and finishes with "Finished with error: Please review your Gradle project setup in the android/ folder."

What command do I use to run that statement in the command line and where do I find the output telling me where to look? This all started when I deleted a launcher icon file. `flutter clean` did not work, nor did opening the project as an Android project and running clean. Now my project won't build for this cryptic reason.

Answer (score 4):

Either run `gradlew -Pandroid.debug.obsoleteApi=true` in the root of your project, or you can add this line `android.debug.obsoleteApi=true` into your `gradle.properties` file.

Answer (score 1):

In Android Studio you can also add the suggested debugging option as a default in the preferences.

> Preferences > Build, Execution, Deployment > Compiler > Command-line Options