# WARNING: API 'BaseVariant.getApplicationIdTextResource' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'VariantProperties.applicationId'

Tags: android, gradle

What dependency should I change dependency to avoid this warning. I am working on openScale (https://github.com/oliexdev/openScale) and can't get project to run in Android Studio.
This is my gradle:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.1'
        classpath "androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:2.3.1"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Safe Args plugin is likely the culprit.

I had the same issue, and tracked it to that using the -Pandroid.debug.obsoleteApi=true flag suggested (see [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57546495/how-to-use-pandroid-debug-obsoleteapi-true-on-the-command-line) for how.

Since you have the same plugin, I assume it will be the same for you as well.

The only solution I could find for now was to change the targetSdkVersion back to 30 (from 31)